# How to change portlet title on tab change in liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-ide, liferay-aui

I have a sample tabview portlet.Which is basically a tabview with 4 tabs.I want to change the portlet title while i change the tabs.

View.Jsp

```
<%


    String redirect = ParamUtil.getString(request, "redirect");
%>
<portlet:renderURL var="viewBackURL" />


<div id="myTab">

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1">Basic Info </a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Address </a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3">Relationship </a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-4">Membership </a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab-1">


            <liferay-util:include page="/html/a.jsp"
                servletContext="<%= application %>">

                <liferay-util:param name="redirect"
                    value="<%= String.valueOf(redirect) %>" />

            </liferay-util:include>

        </div>
        <div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane">
            <liferay-util:include page="/html/b.jsp"
                servletContext="<%= application %>">

                <liferay-util:param name="redirect"
                    value="<%= String.valueOf(redirect) %>" />
            </liferay-util:include>
        </div>



        <div id="tab-3" class="tab-pane">
            <liferay-util:include page="/html/c.jsp"
                servletContext="<%= application %>">



                <liferay-util:param name="redirect"
                    value="<%= String.valueOf(redirect) %>" />
            </liferay-util:include>


        </div>



        <div id="tab-4" class="tab-pane">
            <liferay-util:include page="/html/d.jsp"
                servletContext="<%= application %>">



                <liferay-util:param name="redirect"
                    value="<%= String.valueOf(redirect) %>" />
            </liferay-util:include>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<aui:script>
YUI().use(
  'aui-tabview',
  function(Y) {
    new Y.TabView(
      {
        srcNode: '#myTab'

      }
    ).render();
  }
);

</aui:script>
```

I can change the portlet title using

```
renderResponse.setTitle("My title");
```

How can i change the title while i change the tabs?Can some one help me

Answer (score 0):

For this you will have to use javascript and Css. These links may be helpful.

```
http://www.liferay.com/web/pankaj.kathiriya/blog/-/blogs/usage-of-liferay-js-object

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551639/change-portlet-title-from-code-in-liferay-without-jquery

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582669/change-liferay-portlet-title-in-javascript
```